# Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread. Parse Queries

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I got this warning and find no solution to fix it. In the code below I try to search the username from the parse.com.The error is located at menuItem.text line. Can someone please help me to fix this error .Thank you. 
here is my code.

```
@interface FriendsScene()
 @property(nonatomic) NSArray *user;
@end

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        [query whereKey:@"username" containsString:@"test"];
        self.user =  [[query findObjects]valueForKey:@"username"];

        [self addNode];

    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];

}

-(void)addNode{

// add menu background
menuNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor lightGrayColor] size:CGSizeMake(200, 100)];
menuNode.name = @"menuNode";
menuNode.position = CGPointMake(100, 0);
menuNode.zPosition = 10;
[self addChild:menuNode];



float yPos = -450;

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    SKLabelNode *menuItem = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"HelveticaNeue"];
    menuItem.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"menuItem-%i",i];
    menuItem.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.user objectAtIndex:i]];
    menuItem.fontSize = 20;
    menuItem.fontColor = [SKColor redColor];
    menuItem.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeCenter;
    menuItem.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeCenter;
    menuItem.position = CGPointMake(0, yPos);
    menuItem.zPosition = 25;
    [menuNode addChild:menuItem];

    yPos += 40;
}


}
```

Comment: The warning is not occurring on the menuItem.text line.  It's happening in the completion block at the top here:  self.user =  [[query findObjects]valueForKey:@"username"];  ... findObjects is the offending method.  Maybe me or others can give more help if you remove all of the other code and explain what you want to accomplish in didMoveToView.

Comment: Thank you @danh I want to search the username with string @"test" in the user table of the parse.com and display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find a user with a particular user name, you just need one query on the PFUser class.  Qualify that query with the name you wish to match.  The result will be an array of objects that match:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"username" containsString:@"test"];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        if (objects.count) {
            self.user = objects[0];
        } else {
            // the query worked, but no users were found with that username
        }
        [self addNode];

    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```